# Natural hymen repair

Tags: physiology, reference-request, hymen

When conducting a general Google, most sites that come up are plastic surgery sites advertising "virginity repair" (hymenoplasty or [Hymenorrhaphy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hymenorrhaphy)).

Apart from that, there are articles, for example [Planned Parenthood](https://www.plannedparenthood.org/learn/teens/ask-experts/can-the-hymen-grow-back-if-you-dont-have-sex-for-a-while-and-if-so-would-that-make-you-a-virgin-again), which point out that once the hymen is broken it cannot heal itself. Yet, I have heard of a notion that the hymen can repair itself after sex.

Lo and behold, there is [Joannides, (2008)](https://www.psychologytoday.com/gb/blog/you-it/200806/new-york-times-is-wrong-about-hymens-they-are-not-alone) which states the hymen can heal itself, citing studies which I cannot find.

Is the hymen really able to repair itself? If so, this can have ramifications within the legal profession who use this as proof of penetrative sexual assault and it makes me wonder if there are signs that the hymen was damaged before?

### References

Joannides, P. (2008). *New York Times Is Wrong about Hymens--But They Are Not Alone*. Psychology Today. Retrieved from: https://www.psychologytoday.com/gb/blog/you-it/200806/new-york-times-is-wrong-about-hymens-they-are-not-alone

Comment: Is the hymen really used as evidence of penetrative sex in sexual assault cases in the western world? From what I know it would seem very easy to discredit such evidence.

Comment: @CareyGregory - I was in the public gallery of a court case for rape of a child and the question of hymen damage was raised and examined via medical reports.

Comment: @ChrisRogers Not my area of expertise, but my understanding from more casual but reputable news sources is that use of hymen condition for any purpose is outdated and misleading, yet very often misused. Having it raised in court is not nearly sufficient to make it meaningful, unfortunately.